# T.C to find an element if it is already present in binary heap tree?

Tags: data-structures

What will be the time complexity to find and element if it is already there in a binary heap ?
I think traversal operations are not possible in heap trees !!

Answer (score 0):

In the worst case, one would end up traversing the entire binary heap to search for an element and therefore **the time complexity would be O(N) that is linear in number of elements in the binary heap**

**Binary Heaps are not meant to be used as search data structure. They are used for implementing priority queues and they handle all the operations that are used frequently very well than linear time**

**insert: O(log n)**

**delete: O(log n)**

**increase_key: O(log n)**

**decrease_key: O(log n)**

**extract_max or extract_min: O(log n)**

If you want the search operation to be always **O(log n)** use balanced search trees like **AVL or Red Black trees.**

Comment: @Dante...hope it will go long. Thank you. But my question If a question is give that TC in a big 'O' notation then what will be the answer ?
I do agree i should not traverse the heap but in some forum i am getting answer as O(n) i.e traversal time. I strongly mean it should not be traversed.